# BSTS producing inconsistent results (in R) inspite of setting a seed

Tags: r, bayesian

Anyone else run into this problem?  The results are quite different between each model run (5% to 45%). I see that there is a fix posted on Stack Overflow (https://github.com/rvessenes/bsts), but I am unable to install the tar.gz file.  I am using a Mac, btw.

Any thoughts ?

---

I first downloaded “bsts_0.7.1.1.tar.gz” into my :/…/Library/R/3.5/library

Then, I tried to run the following line inside RStudio.

install.packages("bsts_0.7.1.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, tyype="source")

And yes, I do have BSTS and other dependencies installed.

I also tried type="source".

Comment: Two question not addressed by your question: 1) How did you try the installation. 2) Do you have all the dependencies? From the github page: "If you do not have bsts installed, please install it first to ensure all dependancies are there. (This may require installing Rtools, Boom, and BoomSpikeSlab individually.)". Do NOT use comment s to answer. Use the SO [edit] facilities.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually been going through the same problem. Removing and re-installing the actual bsts package from source seem to have fixed the seed issue. Try downloading the source file for bsts from CRAN, and then install the package

install.packages("path/bsts_0.8.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

I hope this helps, but I am not sure how to fix the compilation issues for https://github.com/rvessenes/bsts.